# Nodejs - iterate directory contents with offset

Tags: node.js, offset, opendir

I know how to stream directory children:

```
let dir = await require('fs').promises.opendir('/path/to/some/dir');
for await (let child of dir) console.log('Child:', dir);
```

I am interested to allow access to this functionality with db-style "offset" and "limit" params, but I am unsure of how to apply the "offset" apart from skipping the first number of results from the `opendir` iterator (and this seems very inefficient, especially for large offsets):

```
let iterateDir = async function*({ offset=0, limit=100 }={}) {
  
  let dir = await require('fs').promises.opendir('/path/to/some/dir');
  let it = dir.entries();
  
  for (let skip = 0; skip < offset; skip++) await it.next();
  
  for (let lim = 0; lim < limit; lim++) yield await it.next();
  
};
```

Is there native filesystem functionality for streaming directory contents from a particular offset, and if so, how can I access this functionality from nodejs? Thanks!

Comment: There is no ability to skip N values in a standard JS iterator.  The only standard accessor they have is `.next()`.  You have to just iterate N times to get to the Nth value.  For random access to the Nth value, you would use an array for your collection from the beginning or use `Array.from()` to load an array from the iterator once and then you have random access from the areray.  A generic iterator does not provide random access of the Nth item.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 yes that's certainly true - this is why I'm asking about native filesystem functionality!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#fspromisesopendirpath-options simply point to the Posix docs for `opendir`, which has no parameters: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html

Node has to work with a variety of filesystems. While this behavior may exist in *some* filesystem (I'm not aware of any), it's definitely not universal. Different filesystems can choose whatever order they please. Perhaps it's insertion order, or perhaps it's last modified. It might not even have a consistent order between calls at all.

Limit and offset only make sense when ordering is guaranteed. There is no contract about the order in which filesystems return the values, so it's not a safe assumption that offsets work even if you ARE iterating over the contents (in fact, this is often true for DBs as well, since rows could be added/deleted in between requests).

Honestly, though, this feels like a premature optimization. The time to iterate over the list of files should be extremely small compared to almost any operation on the files themselves. If you think you'll be skipping thousands and thousands in a row, you can play around with the buffer size and see if it makes a difference:

```js
const dir = await opendir('./', { bufferSize: 1024 })
```